# вывести соавторов автора

Tags: sql

Задача про базу книг, где авторы могут быть авторами нескольких книг, а книги могут иметь несколько авторов. В базе три таблицы:

```
books (bookID, bookTitle, bookAge);
authors (authorID, authorName, authorAge);
indexes (bookID, authorID)
```

Как вывести книги, которые написаны, например - Пупкиным, в соавторстве с кем-то еще? Подскажите как действовать?

Подозреваю, что надо выбрать все книги Пупкина, найти кто еще кроме него их автор, и вывести все эти книги, исключая книги где только Пупкин.

Можно это одним запросом сделать? Куда копать?

Спасибо

Comment: Правильно! Выведите их на чистую воду! А то, понимаешь, присосались к чужому авторству!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Способов такой запрос написать - есть много. Например, так:

```
select bookId, bookTitle 
from books 
    join indexes m2m using(bookID)
    join authors using(authorID)
where authorName = 'Пупкин' and exists (
    select 1 from indexes ao 
    where ao.bookId = m2m.bookID 
        and ao.authorID != m2m.authorID
)
```

Comment: спасибо! проверил, работает ) Прошу пояснить, что делает конструкция "... and exists (select 1 from..."

Comment: И как, например, выбрать всех соавторов Пупкина в книгах с 1960 по 1980 год?

Comment: `exists` - оператор, возвращающий true, если подзапрос вернул хотя бы одну строку. Какие-то данные в подзапросе возвращать бессмысленно, `select какая-то константа` часто используемый вариант. Все соавторы: `select distinct authorID from indexes where bookid in (select bookId from indexes where authorId = :user_id)`. Например так. Комплексно нет настроения сейчас писать. Добавить местами пару джойнов.

Comment: разбираюсь, спасибо, тут в конце, видимо, опечатка? ...where authorId = :user_id)